# Insert empty row/s at the end of the data

Tags: pandas, addition, rows

I have tried `df.loc[df.index.max()+1] = None`,

It did work, but when i tried to run other lines of the script, it got an error.

May I know is there any more code I can use other than this?`df.loc[df.index.max()+1] = None`

Comment: `it got an error`. What was error?

Comment: "cannot reindex from a duplicate axis", but this is for other line. But when i removed df.loc[df.index.max()+1] = None, that error line works for me

Comment: Hmmm, it is weird, is possible see all code?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't give you all the code. But it is related to df.loc[df['ColumnName'].isin['blablabla']]

Comment: Because seems problem is something else.

Answer (score 0):

Sheer concatatenation:

```
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns, data=[[None] * len(df.columns)] * 10)])
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you want to add row containing `None` at the end of data frame. You can do the following in order to keep index in order.

```py
df=df.append({col: None for col in df.columns}, ignore_index=True).reset_index(drop=True)
```